# Assigning events programmatically to a user control

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

Probably this is a naive question, but I didn't find an answer.

I'm creating an UserControl (button like for Winform). Once I have it, I'm using it as a Collection in a Container (really is another UC inherited from Control. I place this container in a form and then I create programmatically a Collection of the "buttons" like this;

```
tMenu.Add(new TrevoButton(Test.Properties.Resources.Mapa, "Map", "MapaClick"));
tMenu.Add(new TrevoButton(Test.Properties.Resources.Inst, "Install", "InstaClick"));
tMenu.Add(new TrevoButton(Test.Properties.Resources.Mode, "Model", "ModelClick"));
```

The parameters are:

- Image (Image): image of the button
- Text (string): text of the button
- Event (string): name of the event to be fired when the "button" is clicked.

My question is that, given the event name, how do I do to assign it like a method for the button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the events defined in another object - e.g. `UserControl` or `Form`? Can you provide a sample of your `TrevoButton` constructor? Also, what type is `tMenu`?

Comment: @lAbstract. Thanks for your comments. The events are defined in the Form that contains the tMenu control. The tMenu control is inherited from Control. This is the TrevoButton definition: "public partial class TrevoButton : UserControl" and this is its consturctor: "public TrevoButton(Image pImagen, string pTexto, string pEvento)". I don't know if it is ok to pass the event name as string parameter.

Comment: You can also pass a pointer to the actual event as a delegate. See my article on code project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/InterfacingMethods.aspx  It should give you enough information to work with. I will work on a small sample for you when I have more time.

Comment: @lAbstract. Thank you! I went to CodeProject, but obviously didn't find the way to search correctly! ;)

Comment: If you have an answer, it is better to post it as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: @LarsTech. Thank for your comment. I'm newbie. May I post my own answer and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what I needed.

This is the ADD to the collection (no quotation marks at the third parameter):

```
tMenu.Add(new TrevoButton(Test.Properties.Resources.Mapa, "Mapa", MapaClick));
```

In the form (same place where I add the items), I'm defining "MapaClick" as:

```
  public void MapaClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("MapaClick");
  }
```

And then, the constructor of the UserControl receives an EventHandler parameter:

```
  public TrevoButton(Image pImagen, string pTexto, EventHandler pEvento)
  {
     Image = pImagen;
     Texto = pTexto;
     this.Click += new EventHandler(pEvento);
     Iniciar();
  }
```

That's it. When I press the button, the message appears!
Thanks to @lAbstract. Your response put me in that way.

Comment: I'm trying to do a simple FishEye effect menu. I will post it in CodeProject as soos as possible.